# How can integrated SDK POS TPS550 to FLUTTER APP

Tags: flutter, sdk, pos

I am developing the application in **Flutter** for a **POS TPS990 terminal**. The app works perfectly but I need to add and use the POS SDK to use the printer and magnetic band reader. I added the libraries to my Android project as the manufacturer says but I can't integrate the methods into the MainActivity to be able to use it. The terminal uses the **Telpo TPS550 SDK**. Someone could give me a hand with this, I'll be grateful.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? I am looking for something similar, any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to copy all the **jar** files and put it in the **libs** directory inside **app** directory. Then right click on each of the **jar** file and select **"Add As Library"**.

[image: like showed on the first image]

Then in the **main** directory create a new directory named **jniLibs**, then copy and paste all the native c++ files.

[image: Like showed in the second picture]

Now you will be able to call SDK api and Classes.

N.B: For apps targeting api 31 there will be ***(blacklist, core-platform-api, reflection, denied)*** which will cause the program to Crash. I have solved the issue using android target SDK 30.